# Inputs inside Partialview takes value from main model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I render a PartialView inside my main View

View:

```
@model FullProductViewModel
...
<div class="send-container">
    @Html.Partial("_CommentForm", new CommentViewModel { ProductId = Model.Id, Title = "" , Context="" })
</div>
```

...

I have a filed with name "Title" in Both my classes "FullProductViewModel" and "CommentViewModel".

_CommentForm PartialView:

```
@model CommentViewModel

<p class="page-title">@Resources.SendComment</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-comment form-submit" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Context)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Context, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Context, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", rows = "8" })
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaptchaCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaptchaCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CaptchaCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="captcha-wrapper">
        <img alt="Captcha" id="imgcaptcha" src="@Url.Action("Captcha", "Captcha")" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit">@Resources.SendMessage</button>
}
```

The problem is "Title" inside PartialView take its value form "FullProductViewModel" model but not "CommentViewModel ". i can easily change the field name "Title" inside one of models to solve problem... but why this happened and how i can fix it without change field name?

Comment: Do your have a `ViewBag.Title = "...";` in your main view (and is it that value that is being displayed)?

Comment: yes. you right. i have `ViewBag.Title = Model.Title;` and what is the solution?

Comment: Changing the name of the property. The `HtmlHelpers` take the values from `ModelState` first (not applicable in your case), then the `ViewDataDictionary` (which includes `ViewBag`) and finally the model value, but it never gets that far because of the `ViewBag` property. You could change the `ViewBag` property, but then you would need to change the Layout file and all views using that, so probably not a good solution in your case

Comment: Thank you for information. taking values in first step from `ViewDataDictionary` instead `model` is a little unfamiliar for me! you can send your comment as an answer so i can accept that as a true answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Title` property is conflicting with the `@{ ViewBag.Title = "..` line of code in your view (the `ViewBag` code is used by the `_Layout.cshtml` file to set the global `<title>` attribute for the page).

All the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls set the `value` by checking (in order)

1. `ModelState`
2. The `ViewDataDictionary` (`ViewData` or `ViewBag`)
3. The value of the models property

In your case, nothing has been added to `ModelState`. But because a value for `Title` has been added to the `ViewDataDictionary`, its that value which is used for the value of your textbox. The method never gets to read the actual value you have set in your model.

The only realistic option (unless you want to modify the code in the `_Layout` and all views that use it) is to change the name of the property.